# Calculate sum of columns in 2D-Array

Tags: for-loop, multidimensional-array

I want to calculate the the sum in each column of a 2D-Array.
So far I got this:

```
public static double[] colMean(double[][] array){
    double arrayCopy[] = new double[array.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        double colSum = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < array.length ; k++){
            colSum = colSum + array[k][i];
        }       
        arrayCopy[i] = colSum; 
    }
    return arrayCopy; 
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can't calculate the sum of an array which has not the exact same number of rows as columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Create a destination array to store column sums
//I'm supposing every row has the same number of columns
for (int i=0; i<array[0].length; i++) {
    destination_array[i]=0;
}

//Traversing the 2D array
for (int i=0;i<array.length; i++) {

    //Adding each column value at the column accumulator
    for (int k=0;k<array[i].length;k++ {
      destination_array[k]+=array[i][k];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That is my problem. What if NOT every row has the same number of columns?

Comment: Then for each row you have to check if this number of columns exist or not. You can do it in the first loop then you will have the right dimensioned destination_array

Answer (score 0):

You loop in 2d arrays as follow:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
        double colSum = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k < array[i].length ; k++){
            colSum = colSum + array[i][k];
        }
```

Comment: But I want to get every column not row.